# play-cache -- memorize an Future with expiration which depends on the value of future

Tags: scala, caching, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

Given following functions

```
val readV : String => Future[V]
val isExpired: V => Boolean
```

*How to memorize the result of `readV` until it `isExpired`by using play cache(or something else)*

Here is how I did:

```
  def getCached(k: String) = Cache.getAs[Future[V]](k)
  def getOrRefresh(k: String) = getCached(k).getOrElse {
    this.synchronized {
      getCached(k).getOrElse {
        val vFut = readV(k)
        Cache.set(k, vFut)
        vFut
      }
    }
  }
  def get(k: String) = getOrRefresh(k).flatMap {
    case v if !isExpired(v) =>  Future.successful(v)
    case _ =>
      Cache.remove(k)
      getOrRefresh(k)
  }
```

This is too complicated to ensure correctness

> Is there any simpler solution to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's possible to change `isExpired: V => Boolean` to `timeToLive: V => Duration`, then you can use

```
def refresh(k: String): Future[V] = readV(k) andThen {
  case Success(v) => Cache.set(k, Future.successful(v), timeToLive(v))
}

def get(k: String): Future[V] = Cache.getOrElse(k)(refresh(k))
```

To control concurrency, I like the actor model:

```
object Lookup {
  case class Get(key: String)


  class LookupActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case Get(key) =>
        Cache.get(key) match {
          case Some(v) => sender ! v
          case None    => val v = Await.result(readV(k), timeout)
                          Cache.set(key, v, timeToLive(v))
                          sender ! v
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Using actors, it'd be nice if we had a `readV` that provides the result synchronously, since the actor model provides the concurrency (and control).

Client-side, it's:

```
val futureV = lookupActor ? Lookup.Get(key) mapTo[V]
```

Comment: How to prevent concurrent `refresh`? That's what I am looking for

Comment: Try looking at `scala.concurrent.SyncVar`, or use a combination of `scala.concurrent.blocking` and `synchronized`. Or you could use an actor, since only one thread operates in an actor instance at a time.

Comment: Is there anyway to get ride of the `await { readV(k) }`, according to my expirence having block call within actor process may cause various of problems

Comment: The only way to guarantee singular access is a single blocking path. The docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#composing-futures) explain that blocking is okay, *when you need to do it*, which is rarely, but it sounds like you require it. A nicer way would be to provide a synchronous `readV` function, then you wouldn't need to block the current thread awaiting the future.

Comment: Note that using `Await` was for a really old (now) version of Akka. Instead of awaiting, today we'd use the pipe pattern in Akka or a `for`-comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good cache implementation by google - https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained (Guava cache)

In our project we are using ScalaCache https://github.com/cb372/scalacache, it abstracts cache layer, and allows to expire values after some timeout by default.

Here is a sample from our code:

```
private val underlyingCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expirationAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).build[String, Object]
implicit val cache = ScalaCache(
    cache = GuavaCache(underlyingCache),
    memoization = MemoizationConfig(toStringConvertor = ParamsToStringConverter))


def getCachedByID(id: String)(implicit format: Format[T]): Option[T] = memoize (cacheTimeout) {
    super.getByID(id)(format)
}
```

In this case memoize is a macros call, that handles generating proper processing. Underlying guava cache is configured to expire values after 1 hour by default, but it can be overridden by cacheTimeout parameter in memoize.

It does not necessarily need to be guava, you can use other supported Cache implmentations, I'm just more familiar and used to guava.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for another cache implemmenation

Comment: You may try to implement the functionality as I described, and it is probably not much simpler